# Echo out a php variable in another web page

Tags: php, html, iframe, echo

I have a web app where, after a function is carried out by the user they are given a notification which tells if they were successful or not for whatever they did. For every function I've declared the variable `$message` which echos out as the notification using the following code:

```
if(isset($message)) {
 echo "<div id='notification'>" . $message . "</div>"
```

My problem is that, for styling purposes, this app needs to be inside an `iframe` inside index.php. The notification is styled `position: absolute; right: 0` but obviously it is confined within the frame whereas it needs to be outside the frame and so it flows with the design (executes outside the frame).

I tried using the same code above with php's `include` but I get no output whatsoever, presumably because `isset` returns NULL since the function isn't executed within index.php.

So my question is, can I either capture the php output and echo it in index.php or run an `iframe` element ( `#notification` ) out side of it's frame.

Thanks. If anyone know's of another work around that'd be welcome. I'm also relatively new to PHP so explanations are welcome too.

Comment: I've tried using include to add the app with php in index.php

Comment: @case1352 any idea what i could do.

Comment: You can make another call to the script with a different parameter set (messages_only=true for example) and display messages separately for the cost of executing script twice.

Comment: @AyeshK can you explain a bit more. I'm not that great with php

Comment: Why don't you simply include the content from the `iframe` into `index.php` ?

Comment: @tftd I did. that's what i meant in the 3rd paragraph

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="put_here_your_iframe_url.php?msg=<?echo urlencode($message);?>" ></iframe>
```

and in iframe

you'll show the message with this line:

```
echo 'Message: '.urldecode($_GET['msg']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to position content outside of an iframe bounding box.

If both iframe content and its parent page are hosted under the same domain you could pass the message from iframe to the parent page using simple JavaScript.

Parent page:

```
<div id="msg"></div>

<script>
var displayNotification = function( message ){ document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = message; }
</script>
```

Change in your PHP script

```
if(isset($message)) {
echo "<script> top.displayNotification(" . $message . ");</script>";
```